# How to submit parameter to a quick action?

Tags: javascript, quickaction

i have a quick action with two fields. I want to submit a parameter for one field.
How can i do this?

I have already specified a prefdefined field value and a button on a custom vf-page.

```
var newTestpoint = $('<a href="services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Warengruppen_Struktur__c/quickActions/Neuer_Endpunkt/defaultValues/?Parent_Warengruppe__c={!FolderId}"> Testbutton | </a>');
$nodeSpan.append(newTestpoint);
```